# Error: NoSuchMethodError: The Method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("name")

Tags: flutter

I am new on software development and I am using flutter and trying to retrieve a document from the backend, but I am getting an error.
Here's my code below...

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../rest_ds.dart';

class DocumentsHandler{

  RestDatasource _restDatasource = GetIt.I<RestDatasource>();

  Future<List<DownloadTask>> getDownloads() async {
    return await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();
  }

  Future<DownloadTask> getDownloadByName(String filename) async {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE file_name = '$filename'";
    List<DownloadTask> downloads = await FlutterDownloader
    .loadTasksWithRawQuery(query: query);

    if(downloads.length > 0){
     return downloads.removeLast();
  }

  return null;
}

 Future<List> getDocumentsOnline() async {
   Response response =  await _restDatasource.getDocuments();
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
}

Future<List<DownloadTask>> loadDocuments() async {
  List onlineDocuments = await getDocumentsOnline();
  Directory externalStorageDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

 /*onlineDocuments.forEach((document) async {

  });*/

  for(int i = 0; i < onlineDocuments.length; i++){
    var document = onlineDocuments.elementAt(i);
    DownloadTask downloadTask = await getDownloadByName(document["document"]["name"]);
   if( downloadTask == null){
    print("Enqueue");
    await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: _restDatasource.buildFileDownloadUrl(document["document"]["id"]),
        savedDir: externalStorageDirectory.absolute.path,
        fileName: document["document"]["name"],
        showNotification: true,
        requiresStorageNotLow: false
      );
    }
  }
   return this.getDownloads();
  }
}
```

And Below is the error I'm getting on my emulator. What exactly is null because I can't seem to figure out what it is?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE6Fp.png)

please help!!!

Comment: Check whether `document["document"]` is null or not

Comment: Are you sure it's `document["document"]["name"]` and not `document["name"]` ? You should build a DocumentModel to transform your data that you retreive from your API to object. So you flutter code will be more consistent.

Comment: @BabC If I run document["name"] I get this error... `Error: package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart: failed assertion: line 152pos 12: _initialized: FlutterDownloader.initialize() must be called first`

Comment: @MidhunMP how exactly do I check if `document["document"]` is null. I am still new to software development and I haven't found any documentation with that info.

Comment: Ronny what is document ? Did you print that out?

Comment: Please use print to check where actually it is null